# Google Or Tools Prefer more vehicles than saving cost

Tags: python, google-visualization, or-tools

I had total of 8 vehicles and have travel time, weight as cost parameter for route calculation. Below image is showing the plans created and Google OR-Tools has created plans for only five vehicles. If you note the green plan that is created, it is sending vehicle on left side and then on the right side serving the locations. Is there a way that i can engage more vehicles than making long travel plans? Ideally the green vehicle should have been sent on right side or left side only, instead of traveling to both direction despite the weight, time and no of locations to visit are left.

These are search parameters that i have specified

```
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
    routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(3)
```

[image]

Comment: the issue does not lie in the search, but in the objective. Please search, this questions has been asked a lot.

Comment: I tried searching for this issue but could not find any direction about how can i do this !

Comment: @LaurentPerron, i want to utilized more vehicles rather than saving the vehicles, as one vehicle is traveling a long distance.

Comment: search for global span

Answer (score 1):

Here are some helpful links for `Global_Span` which could be useful if you want to utilize more vehicles by setting it on distance dimension for example.

```
  /// Sets a cost proportional to the *global* dimension span, that is the
  /// difference between the largest value of route end cumul variables and
  /// the smallest value of route start cumul variables.
  /// In other words:
  /// global_span_cost =
  ///   coefficient * (Max(dimension end value) - Min(dimension start value)).
  void SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(int64_t coefficient);
```

[Reference](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8cea0ef3b9e8296d866c61453697253b043a60a1/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2842-L2848)

[vrp_global_span.py (Sample)](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8cea0ef3b9e8296d866c61453697253b043a60a1/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_global_span.py)